# Create TAB and create textboxes that take data in the TAB-page

Tags: class, tabs, textbox, pyqt

I am working in PyQt. The existing code (extremely long and sources almost all the org.'s s/w) has sections which is responsible for creating tabs and textboxes. But, being a newbie to PyQt, I am not clear on how it all works. For my part, I need to do the following:
(1) Create a TAB titled 'xyz' within the row of all the other tabs.
(2) Create 6 textboxes with individual labels in the page displyed by the created TAB where the user can enter data and save it.

These are the two immediate problems I have to deal with now. Later,

The data entered in the textboxes will replace the data in bar-graphs (in another window) as soon as the data in the textboxes is entered and saved. This is to be done afterwards but first I need to solve the 2 issues listed above. The imports are all there in the (longish) code and I have to insert my new code within that code - perhaps by creating a new class. Can you help? Thanks. And, please let me know if you need any information to work on this.
[image: Create TAB+TEXTBOXES]

EDIT::::::::::: Have inserted the image below. As you can see, at the top of the left pane, there are multiple tabs in a row (all made in PyQt). I need to create a tab like the last one (here, titled-Incentives) with a blank page like the one shown below the tab. Within the page, I need to create 2 sets of textboxes, 3 textboxes in each set with labels for the set(s) and the individual textboxes. Data entered in the boxes will be integers(20) and the data will then go on to populate/update a dynamic stacked bar graph. At this point, I want to ask another question. When the data updates the graph, should it be first saved in the DB (the DB which is primarily responsible for the initial figures in the graph) and then routed to the graph or should the data update the graph directly, bypassing the DB and if so, won't the graph revert to its earlier values and forget the data from the textboxes once it is reset. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here you have a code that you can use as a starting point for your own development. It creates a `QTabWidget` with two tabs. The "Tab 1" tab contains a vertical layout with two groupboxes. Groupboxes contain labels and textboxes arranged in a grid. The other tab is empty.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        # Create the tabbed widget
        self.central = QTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)

        # Create a new tab
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        # Tab has a vertical layout
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.tab1)
        # Tab children: two groups containing a grid of labels and textboxes
        self.group1 = QGroupBox("Group 1")
        self.textBox1 = QLineEdit(self.group1)
        self.textBox2 = QLineEdit(self.group1)
        self.fillGroup(self.group1, self.textBox1, self.textBox2)
        self.group2 = QGroupBox("Group 2")
        self.textBox3 = QLineEdit(self.group2)
        self.textBox4 = QLineEdit(self.group2)
        self.fillGroup(self.group2, self.textBox3, self.textBox4)
        # Add tab children to the tab layout
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.group1)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.group2)
        # Append tab to the tabbed widget
        self.central.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab 1")

        # Create a new tab and append it to the tabbed widget
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.central.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab 2")

    def fillGroup(self, group, box1, box2) :
        """Arrange the groupbox content in a grid layout"""

        grid = QGridLayout(group)
        label1 = QLabel("Input 1:", group)
        grid.addWidget(label1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(box1, 0, 1)
        label2 = QLabel("Input 2:", self.group1)
        grid.addWidget(label2, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(box2, 1, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MyMainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please notice that for my convenience I've used a `QMainWindow` as a parent for the tabbed widget. Obiously you can use other widgets as parent if you need it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again, Vicent! I checked out some of the examples of QMainWindow and am not sure if it meets the requirements here. Maybe I am not looking at the right places. What I wanted is the following. Here's a screenshot of the requirement.

Comment: I edited the screenshot in the question above with some explanation of the problem and a supplementary question at the end as well.

Comment: If you already have the tabbed widget but don't understand how it works, then locate it in your code and add a tab as explained in my answer (i.e. create a tab widget, give it a layout, create children widgets, add children to layout and finally add tab to the tabbed widget). If you are not satisfied when the result you get then post a new question (including some code, if possible). Please, don't add supplementary questions to your original post, simply post a new question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Let me try. And thanks for the advice on supplemental questions-I'll use a different page for new queries. And will let you know the results of my attempts. Best,

Comment: I've updated my answer to use groupboxes as I see it is one of your requirements. Just one more advice, if all this discussion has been useful for you, please consider to upvote/accept the answer. It will increase your reputation/acceptance score and other users will be more willing to help you in the future.

Comment: Thanks Vicent. It has definitely helped me. But apparently, I need 15 points to be eligible to upvote an answer and currently I have only 11.

Comment: Check your reputation again ;-) You can read the FAQ to make sure you use StackOverflow properly. It will help you to improve your scores