# Running Pyqt UIs in tabs using TabWidget

Tags: user-interface, tabs, pyqt4

I want to run my app in different tabs. Rightnow, it is  running in main window. I have done some search work on how to create tabs. I found this to be useful, but not sufficient to meet my requirements

[Create TAB and create textboxes that take data in the TAB-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637871/create-tab-and-create-textboxes-that-take-data-in-the-tab-page)

I want to have a feature of adding a new tab (like new tab in chrome)
Below is my code sample. I described what i require in the comments.

```
from PyQt4 import Qt, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
class Map(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self,parentQExampleScrollArea=None,parentQWidget = None):
    super(Map,self).__init__()
    self.initUI()


#Initialize the UI
def initUI(self):
    #Initilizing Menus toolbars
    #This must be maintained in all tabbed panes
    filename = ""
    #Filename is obtained through open file button in file menu
    self.filename = filename

def paintEvent(self, e):

    qp = QtGui.QPainter()
    qp.begin(self)

    self.drawPoints(qp,self.filename)

    qp.end()

def drawPoints(self, qp,FILENAME=""):
    #Read contents in file
    #Get the necessary coordinates
    #A separate class for storing the info of all the coordinates

    #Run a for loop for all the coordinates in the list
    #Actually, object is created here and image of that object is set
    # as  a square using the coordinates
    qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 20, 200))        
    qp.drawRect(20,20,75,75)
    qp.drawRect(100,20,75,75)
    self.update()

    #There are many functions to handle keyboard and mouse events



def main():
#How do I modify so that I can have multiple tabs
#And show images of the coordinates in files
#Basically I want to have the feature of opening many files
# and displaying them in UI
#Basically a feature to add a new tab
#like that of in eclipse netbeans sublime etc

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myQExampleScrollArea = Map()
myQExampleScrollArea.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's simply to use method [int QTabWidget.addTab (self, QWidget widget, QString)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtabwidget.html#addTab) to create widget in tab. In each tab, I suggest use `QtGui.QWidget` more than `QtGui.QMainWindow`;

Example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    # Your widget to implement
    # Put your override method here

    def paintEvent (self, eventQPaintEvent):
        currentQPainter = QtGui.QPainter()
        currentQPainter.begin(self)
        currentQPainter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 20, 200))        
        currentQPainter.drawRect(20, 20, 75, 75)
        currentQPainter.drawRect(100, 20, 75, 75)
        self.update()
        currentQPainter.end()

class QCustomTabWidget (QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.addTab(QtGui.QPushButton('Test'), 'Tab 1')
        self.addTab(QCustomWidget(),           'Tab 2')

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomTabWidget = QCustomTabWidget()
myQCustomTabWidget.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

So handle with more tab, It's bad to create many line call `int QTabWidget.addTab (self, QWidget widget, QString)`. Anyway, All widget has add in `QTabWidget` is can reference in ifself. So, your can control element in it by call [`QWidget QTabWidget.widget (self, int index)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtabwidget.html#widget).

Example to call widget in tab widget;

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class QCustomLabel (QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, imagePath, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomLabel, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))

class QCustomWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomWidget, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.addQPustButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Open image')
        self.addQPustButton.setMaximumWidth(120)
        self.addQPustButton.released.connect(self.openImage)
        self.workSpaceQTabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.workSpaceQTabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.workSpaceQTabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeImage)
        allQVBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        allQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.addQPustButton)
        allQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.workSpaceQTabWidget)
        self.setLayout(allQVBoxLayout)

    def openImage (self):
        path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open image')
        if not path.isEmpty():
            self.workSpaceQTabWidget.addTab(QCustomLabel(path), QtCore.QString(os.path.basename(str(path))))

    def closeImage (self, currentIndex):
        currentQWidget = self.workSpaceQTabWidget.widget(currentIndex)
        currentQWidget.deleteLater()
        self.workSpaceQTabWidget.removeTab(currentIndex)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomWidget = QCustomWidget()
myQCustomWidget.show() 
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks kitsune (again .. I remembered you answering my previous question too). Yeah I can implement this, but the problem is that I deal with lot of global variables. Each tab should rerun the whole program .Yeah, I can make global variables to instance variables but that makes my code more messy .. Please suggest on this.

Comment: So your want to auto add widget in tab just like in web browser and by not create variables in them ? I don't know I understand your say corrected, but please read my last edited answer.

Comment: yes this will be helpful.. I will try modifying my code to make to it work.